# Version control system on distributed files or database?

Tags: database, version-control, distributed

Do you know of any "version control" or sync tool able to work transparently on files stored on distributed file systems (such as Hadoop) or using their own database to keep the files?

I'm looking for something able to keep track of the different versions of source code files and any files on folders.

I think svn, git, mercurial, sharepoint...  won't allow me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PlasticSCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/home.html)?

I think it could fit your requirements. Check the [Features](https://www.plasticscm.com/features/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look, though I think it can't work (as the source) with data stored on a distributed database. It's the software itself who is distributed and stores its own data on a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a distributed version control system for databases, check out [Klonio](https://klonio.com). Its like Git/GitHub for databases.